# Access a site from different computer on same LAN

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, routing, port-forwarding

I have two computers, one of them new and another one old which has an ethernet port and the new one doesn't. I wish to the connect to one of my router's web client settings via LAN cable through the ethernet port, the problem is that old computer's screen is damaged (not totally) and if i could access the router web page in a new computer it would be really helpful. That is when i type the router ip adresss(192.168.1.1) can i make it go through the old computer that has the ethernet port(connected to the router) so that i can access its page. Both computer's are connected wirelessly with an another router that has an ip address like (192.168.0.x) I digged a little but i only ended up seeing about accessing a site that is locally hosted. I can provide more clarification if necessary, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you rdp to the old computer from the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have both pc connected to the internet and in the same lan you can run any remote desktop solution ( remote desktop, teamviewer, Ammyy etc.) and connect to the web page from there.

Comment: Remote Desktop was something i came across, but i was thinking of something along the lines of Networking, because the problem seemed rather too simple at first, but as i dig’d more it’s seems almost impossible. Seems I’d have to settle with RD.